# "My Calendar" and "PC Sync" -- How to Delete?

Tags: calendar, htc-sense, htc-sync-3.0

These two (empty) calendars appear in the list of calendars inside the stock calendar app (at least on HTC Sense setups). I'm not entirely sure what they are but they are both unused and cluttering things up. I know I can hide them but is there anyway to just make them gone? When I select Remove Calendars, they don't show up in the list.

Why would anyone want to sync a calendar to a PC anyway? That's the big advantage to a cloud calendar like Google's...

More Information:
I have installed HTC's desktop Sync app (not for syncing, for development related things).

Comment: PC Sync appears regardless of whether you have installed the sync app

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete them but you can uncheck them so no information from them shows in the calendar.

Many folks are still using Outlook for calendaring and need the ability to sync with the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

That must be an HTC Sense thing; no such calendars ever existed on my Droid.

It doesn't look like you'll be able to get rid of them short of rooting your phone.

Answer (score -1):

For calendars. Go to the calendar. touch any day. then hit menu. then hit more. then select calendars. then un-check facebook. (at least one calendar has to be selected btw. it took off all the birthdays.

for contacts. hit people. hit menu. select view. then check just phone.
however when you search some things. facebook contacts somehow still are searched. So i dont know how to remove them COMPLETELY.

thanks to Micah Reuben Charles Perez

http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?topic=15423&post=112530&uid=41158896424#!/topic.php?uid=41158896424&topic=15423