# Any chance to get rid of "PC Sync" calendar entirely?

Tags: calendar, 8.1-oreo

[Ten years later](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/449/20449)... Can someone explain me, how did I get "PC Sync" calendar to my stock calendar app on my Android 8.1 / Neffos X9 and -- the most important -- how to get rid of it?

I know, I can uncheck it (what I did) and I won't see any events from it. But, I want to get rid of it entirely. The thing is that it appear on the top of the list of my calendars, when I creating each and every new event, which pisses me a little bit.

Since I've been using Android 8.0 / 8.1 for 1+ year and "PC Sync" appeared just a week ago or so, I'd like to also know what I did or what happened that I was free of it (and happy) for year and now I am forced to see it everywhere around my Calendar app.